# Perl:Undefined subroutine &main

Tags: perl, cgi

One of my non-developer friend asked my help about that issue. I am a windows developer, i don`t know anything about Perl, also script languages. I tried to search the issue but could not find a solution. Is there anyone can tell me what is the problem here and how to fix it.

Error after clicking the button:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::quote_javascript called at /usr/libexec/webmin/chooser.cgi line 192.
```

And the line 192 is :

```
$link = "<a href=\"\" onClick='fileclick(\"".&quote_javascript("$dir$f")."\", $isdir); return false'>";
```

Comment: That cannot be the right line, since there is no subroutine `quote_javascript` on that line. Most likely, it is a broken dependence -- a module you have not loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The code that's actually triggering the error is of the form

```
... quote_javascript(...) ...
```

You are calling a sub named `quote_javascript` (in the current package, `main`). There is no sub named `quote_javascript` (in the current package, `main`).